# How to wait for ADB push to complete?

Tags: bash, adb

Some automation setup requires files be loaded onto Android devices.. Internal memory does not refresh automatically when ADB push completes.

My current script loops through ADB commands sequentially for every device simultaneously, then sleeps and triggers a memory scan via the action.MEDIA_MOUNTED broadcast:

```
adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        #Additional ADB commands
        #Load files
        adb -s $device push home/test/test-automation-agent/loadondevice/. /sdcard &
    fi
done

#Wait for push to complete
sleep 30

adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
            #Trigger refresh of internal storage
            adb -s $device shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file://mnt/sdcard 
    fi
done
```

The time required to execute ADB push can change dramatically. I would like to replace the sleep with something that detects ADB push completion and executes the broadcast.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered putting the push and broadcast in the same command chain and backgrounding the whole thing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do that. I did try broadcasting inside the first loop, but the scan is obviously premature.

Comment: `{ adb ... ; adb ... ; } &`

Comment: Oh, right! Thank you. This is the best solution so far, but each device is handled sequentially and not simultaneously.

Comment: The first `adb` pushes, and the second broadcasts. Both target the same device.

Comment: I get that, but the commands for subsequent devices are forced to wait for the current device's ADB push, which ends up taking longer.
As written in the question, all commands are executed sequentially, and all devices simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ADBDevices () {
  adb devices | awk -F"\t" '/\tdevice$/{print $1}'
}

ADBPushAndScan () {
  adb -s $1 push home/test/test-automation-agent/loadondevice/. /sdcard
  adb -s $1 shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file://mnt/sdcard
}

Wait () {
  while [ $(jobs | grep Running | wc -l) -ne 0 ]; do sleep 1; done
}

for device in $(ADBDevices); do
  ADBPushAndScan $device &
done

Wait
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `sleep 30` and put `wait` instead in order to wait for all children to exit.

Comment: I made this change, but the wait doesn't seem to have any affect. The broadcast immediately follows the other commands.